# MS Word style text indentation in WPF (using Richtextbox)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, richtextbox, rtf, wpf-4.0

I am implementing a WPF 4.0 multitouch application, which performs text formatting based on gestures. While I have managed to achieve a few kinds of text formatting, I am having difficulty in realizing text indentation (MS Word style). By MS word style, I mean when left/right indentation is performed:

- If the selected text amounts to a single paragraph (or lesser), indent that whole paragraph.
- If no text is selected, indent the entire paragraph, where the caret is present.
- If the selected text amounts to more than one paragraph, indent all the selected paragraphs entirely. In this case, the paragraphs may be either partially or fully selected.

I found a few solutions, but none seem to work for me at the moment. I use a RichTextBox control, which I have created in my XAML file. I want to perform the text indentation in the code behind. Could someone please let me know how I can achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned that you want to do this in code behind, but this all can be done in the XAML itself.  I imagine you're using C#.

`using System.Windows.Documents;`

XAML (I'll be using a button example, command could be used anywhere):

```
<Button Name="increaseIndentButton" Command="EditingCommands.IncreaseIndentation"/>
<Button Name="decreaseIndentButton" Command="EditingCommands.DecreaseIndentation"/>
<RichTextBox Name="myRichTextBox" AcceptsTab="True"/>
```

Using the `EditingCommands` will satisfy all of your requirements listed above.

> - If the selected text amounts to a single paragraph (or lesser), indent that whole paragraph.
> - If no text is selected, indent the entire paragraph, where the caret is present.
> - If the selected text amounts to more than one paragraph, indent all the selected paragraphs entirely. In this case, the paragraphs may be
>     either partially or fully selected.

Moreover, increasing and decreasing indentation have hotkeys, Ctrl+T and Ctrl+Shift+T respectively.

More information is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.editingcommands(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I cannot use buttons since it is a gesture based application that I am implementing. But the using the EditingCommands that you suggested, got the desired results for me. Thank you!